# about advance in STL

Tags: c++, stl

the define of function `advance()` is :

```
template<class InIt, class Dist>
void advance(
        InIt& it, 
        Dist n
);
```

when i use this function in my code:

```
string strArr[10];
strArr[0] = string("dd");
strArr[1] = string("gg");
strArr[2] = string("tt");
const vector<string> vecStr(strArr, strArr+6);
advance(vecStr.begin(), 2);
cout<<*(vecStr.begin())<<endl; // the output is dd
```

**You know the first parameter in function `advance()` is reference**, so after `advance(vecStr.begin(), 2);`, `verStr.begin()` should point to `vecStr[2]`.
But from the output we find `vecStr.begin()` points to `str[0]`.

I want to know wy?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile, as you are binding a non-const reference to a temporary.  The fact that it does is a deficiency/extension in Visual C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
advance(vecStr.begin(), 2);
cout<<*(vecStr.begin())<<endl; // the output is dd
```

You are using two different iterators, one of which you use `advance` on, and the other which you use in printing.

For your code to work, use [`advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) and `cout` on the same iterator

```
auto iter = vecStr.begin();
advance(iter , 2);
cout << *iter << endl;
```

---

Just a comment in your original code, `advance(vecStr.begin(), 2);` won't actually compile, at least if you are using strict compiler settings. `vecStr.begin()` returns a temporary object, one which cannot be bound to the first parameter of `std::advance` which is an l-value reference.

---

Also, [`std::vector::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) logically returns a copy of the actual begin iterator inside the vector, not a reference to it. This means that whatever you do to the returned iterator will not be reflected to the begin iterator inside the vector. I'm talking about the iterators here, not the elements they point to.

Comment: you konw the first paramer in function is an reference, so when i do advance(vecStr.begin(), 2); the value of vecStr.begin() should change.

Comment: @BlackMamba, Who said anything about `begin()` returning the same iterator each time.

Comment: @BlackMamba Yeah, but you are advancing a *copy* of the `.begin()` iterator of the vector. Also take note of my edit.

Answer (score 1):

`std::advance` will not change iterator underneath `std::vector`, also your advance on a *temporary iterator*

```
// this will advance on a temporary iterator returned from vecStr.begin()
// it shouldn't compile as C++ doesn't allow bind reference to temporary object
advance(vecStr.begin(), 2);
```

The reason you could compile your code is that you are using Visual Sutdio extention [C4239](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/186yxbac.aspx), sometimes known as ***evil*** extension.

You should do:

```
auto biter = vecStr.begin();    // biter points to begin of vecStr
std::advance(biter, 2);         // advance biter by 2 position
std::cout<< *biter << std::endl;
```

Comment: there is no temporary, because the first parameter in advance is reference.

Comment: @BlackMamba Read up on rvalues, xvalues, prvalues, lvalues, and glvalues.

Comment: @BlackMamba advance does take first argument as ref, but begin() only returns a copy

Comment: By the way, this answer is wrong. You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference so the code shouldn't even compile. There's no advancing of temporaries.

Answer (score 0):

`vector::begin()` is a function returning an iterator. You can't change what `begin()` returns by modifying the iterator it returns - you can only change what it returns by modifying the vector contents.

Try this instead:

```
auto it = vecStr.begin();
advance(it, 2);
cout<<*(it)<<endl;
```

Comment: `std::advance` is a standard function that advances the iterator by n steps (yet another reason `using namespace std` is bad).

Comment: Doh! :) <smacks head>

Answer (score 0):

Your code [does not compile under a standards conforming compiler](http://ideone.com/8Xzc3H). I'm guessing you're using Visual Studio and your warning level isn't high enough to tell you about taking references of temporaries.

[`vector::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) does not return a *reference* to an iterator. It returns an iterator *by value*; it returns a temporary. `std::advance`'s first parameter is a non-const reference. And those are, in standard C++, *not allowed* to bind to an argument that is a temporary. So your code fails to compile.

But on VS, where this is allowed, this doesn't do what you want because you're advancing a *temporary object*, not what's actually "stored" in the `vector`. After all, a `vector` may not actually store these things; they may be generated from arbitrary data. So you can't simply modify iterators in a `vector`, because a `vector` may not *have iterators* in it.